# Hard disk usage 100% after a failure desk mount operation

Tags: hard-drive, dvd

I was trying to burn a DVD on my computer, I used the ultraISO software to burn it and it gave me an error. I searched on the internet and found a 3rd party app called ImgBurn. I used it to burn my DVD, but I think that something wrong happened. It was stuck at 0% for more than 15 minutes. I tried to exit the operation but it didn't let me. I tried to take off the DVD but it didn't stop spinning and I couldn't open the cd place in order to take it off.

I unplugged my computer and plugged it back in when the dvd stopped spinning, and when it opened up I got the disk usage 100% should I worry? And how would I fix that?

Comment: have disk at 100% it is a problem (normally) for performance and for OS usage, anyway you have to determinate what is use a lot of space, you can use windir stat, it will give you a report of file and their dimension. I use IMGBURN for long time and I get never a issue, may be caused by the system disk is full?